# Reflect the changes made in configuration of spring application during run time without rebuilding it

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, web-deployment

I have a Spring Boot application running , so is there any way that if I make some changes in the configuration (changes in application.properties or pom.xml) of the application these changes are reflected during the run time without  rebuilding the application and deploying it again?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Actuator for Spring Boot to refresh the properties. Check below the link.

https://stackabuse.com/spring-boot-configuring-properties/

Comment: Can we use Actuator for Spring MVC application as well?

Comment: I have not used Actuator in Spring MVC, I have used in Spring Boot application.